# Can't build project on Ubuntu using QT6.4 and CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

I installed a fresh new copy of QTCreator on a Ubuntu VM. It is a clean virtual machine. Then I create a dummy QTQuick project with almost nothing in it. But creator fails to compile, saying CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  not found. See message below:

```
error: No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found. Tell CMake where to find the compiler by 
setting either the environment variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER 
to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

Am I missing the compiler? This is a fresh install and I don't understand. Creator is showing the only compiler option. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Any ideas why it does not compile from a clean install, using all default option? The compiler must be there.

thank you.

Comment: "The compiler must be there." - So, do you actually have a compiler or do you think so? It is easy to check: the package providing a C++ compiler is named `g++`.

Comment: Open a `Terminal` window (e.g. xterm). And type `g++`. Also, whilst you are at it, type `cmake`. If there are issues, then work through them first. You may need to install `build-essential` if you haven't already done so.

Comment: how do I install build-essential? sudo apt install build-essencial?

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instructions and it worked finally.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get -y install build-essential openssl libssl-dev libssl1.0 libgl1-mesa-dev libqt5x11extras5
```

downloaded the install and made it executable

```
chmod +x qt*.run
```

then it worked.

Here is the page with more explanations:

https://web.stanford.edu/dept/cs_edu/resources/qt/install-linux